# iOS UI-Test simulate (changing) Location

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing

I have some kind of navigation app where I handle different locations. Is it possible in UI tests to simulate and even to change them at runtime? What would be the best approach to archive this?

Comment: Use gpx file and add location in it.

Comment: Thats clear and it works in manual tests. But not in UI Tests

Comment: You will have to add the GPX file to the *app* target, not UI Test target for this approach to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best approach to this will be to use GPX files.  These allow you to set the lat and long of a location. (For more details see here: https://blackpixel.com/writing/2013/05/simulating-locations-with-xcode.html)

However, I suspect you will need to call these from within the app itself and then use UI testing launch arguments (when you launch XCUIApplication) to stipulate which GPX files to use depending upon the test.

Answer (score 0):

See my detailed note https://github.com/onmyway133/blog/issues/45

1. You need to declare the gpx file in the app target, not the UI Tests target
2. Go to `Simulator -> Location -> Custom Location` to point to your location in the gpx. It is duplication, but without it, it does not work
3. If it does not work because of caching or something, run the app again, then run UI Tests again.
4. If it still does not work, reset simulator
5. You can create gpx file directly from Xcode

[image]